# Preventing unauthorized member for joining Hazelcast cluster

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are changing one of our application to use Hazelcast 3.11 Community Edition  and do some locking between multiple JVMs running on a few hosts.
We configure our cluster grammatically like below:

```
public class HazelcastBuilder {
    private final String name;
    private final String password;
    private final String members;
    private final String hostName;
    private final String applicationName;

    public HazelcastInstance getHazelcastInstance() {
        Config hazelcastConfig = new Config();
        GroupConfig groupConfig = new GroupConfig(name, password);
        hazelcastConfig.setGroupConfig(groupConfig);

        TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = new TcpIpConfig();
        tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true);
        for (String member : members.split(",")) {
            tcpIpConfig.addMember(member.trim());
        }

        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().setTcpIpConfig(tcpIpConfig);
        // By default the multicast config is enabled. Disable it here.
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        String instanceName = applicationName + "-" + hostName;
        hazelcastConfig.setInstanceName(instanceName);

        logger.info("Creating hazelcast instance: " + instanceName);
        return Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig);
    }
}
```

All works fine and the cluster gets created properly and working as expected.

However I created an unit tests and configured a local cluster with the same name as the application uses then I added my developer machine to it. All worked fine and my local host joined the application cluster without any issues.

Of course such a thing cannot be accepted in a production environment and here is my question for:

Given we have a list of host names that can run our application what is the best way to prevent unauthorized member to join a given hazelcast cluster.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for security features, then you should use Hazelcast Enterprise edition. Check the feature lists:

- [OS features](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/imdg-features/)
- [EE features](https://hazelcast.com/product-features/imdg-comparison/)

If you only need to prevent arbitrary machines connecting to your cluster, then there are several options in the opensource edition:

- use a unique group name for each of your clusters;
- as an additional level of protection you can define a validation token in your configuration - just set `hazelcast.application.validation.token` Hazelcast property (or system property) - look at [reference manual](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.4/manual/html-single/index.html#system-properties) for details
- specify which network interfaces should be used ([doc](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.4/manual/html-single/index.html#interfaces)) and disable binding to all local interfaces by setting `hazelcast.socket.bind.any` property to `false`. Usually, your production cluster runs in a trusted LAN environment so you want to make it accessible only within that LAN.
- Multicast discovery mechanism ([doc](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.4/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-members-by-multicast)) adds also the `<trusted-interfaces>` configuration, which could help you. You're using TCP discovery, so it's not valid for your scenario.

Final note: The group password field is not checked in Hazelcast opensource edition!

Comment: I ended up using `hazelcast.application.validation.token=node1,node2,node3` where node1, node2 and node3 are the names of the hosts running my application. It worked like a charm and even got a warning in the logs when another node tried to join the cluster:

Comment: @Julian, Would you mind sharing how did you make it happen? Did you do it declaratively or programatically.

Did you add diferent passwords, or the "node1,node2,node3" is one password as a whole?

If they are different passwords, did you manage call the hostname per node in order to be authenticated in hazelcast?

Comment: I done it grammatically but the nodes names in the cluster were loaded from a properties file. Just be aware that this works fine only in the case the hacker does'n know the hosts names. If the hacker knows them and has access to the network were those hosts belong to then my solution will not work.

Comment: `validation.token` should not be used IMO. This is what I get if tried with a false token. It prints the correct one too.
`Node could not join cluster. A Configuration mismatch was detected: Incompatible 'hazelcast.application.validation.token'! expected: U8fHwYS2mG, found: U8fHwYS2mG123 Node is going to shutdown now!`

I think its sole purpose is to keep the configs in sync.