# Restrict members in Hazelcast cluster

Tags: hazelcast

I am working on a spring boot project where i am using Hazelcast as Cache. I have enabled tcp as join method and i also mentioned some members. The members are able to join. But the problem is other nodes are also able to join apart from the members. can anyone tell me how i can restrict it?

This is my configuration,

```
@Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config()
                .setClusterName("myCluster");
        List<String> members = new ArrayList<>();
        members.add("192.168.99.1:5523");
        members.add("192.168.99.2:5542");
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin()
                .setMulticastConfig(new MulticastConfig().setEnabled(false))
                .setTcpIpConfig(new TcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).setMembers(members));
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5523);
        return config;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537398/hazelcast-community-edition-security)

Answer (score 1):

The main approach in the Hazelcast IMDG (community edition) is to configure the different cluster names.

You can also look into Hazelcast Enterprise which has a set of security features (JAAS authentication, TLS, symmetric encryption, ...).

More details in these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62540153/653069
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56216106/653069

Comment: thank you Kwart. But is there any feature to restrict to only mentioned members? as you can see i have given only two members. Then it should join with only those two members right? or am i doing something wrong here?.

Comment: No such restriction (existing feature) comes to my mind. The assumption about "only those two" is not correct. The member joining a cluster first sends "who is master" question to predefined members. After receiving the master address it connects to it with the Join request. If the join operation is successful then the master sends an updated member list to all cluster members. So the member addresses defined in the configuration just mean "addresses known to be part of the cluster".

Comment: You could use member addresses in the cluster name. For instance, sort all the addresses alphabetically, and concatenate them into the ClusterName configuration field. If all members on your network follow this scheme (i.e. no malicious member in your network), then they're only able to connect to their own cluster. To make it safe you should also disable the port auto-increment and explicitly set the member IP address in Network/Interfaces configuration.