# Hazelcast tcp-ip configuration cluster: Unwanted IPs join the cluster even after cluster-name is specified

Tags: tcp, hazelcast, multicast

I have two hazelcast configure yaml files:

hazelcast-cluster1.yml:

```
  hazelcast:
    cluster-name: cluster1
    network:
      join:
        multicast:
          enabled:false
        tip-ip:
          enabled: true
          member-list:
           machineA
           machineB
```

hazelcast-cluster2.yml:

```
  hazelcast:
    cluster-name: cluster2
    network:
      join:
        multicast:
          enabled:false
        tip-ip:
          enabled: true
          member-list:
           machineC
           machineD
```

What I wanted is machineA and machineB forms a cluster while machineC and machineD does a separate cluster.  However, when I started machineC, it forms a cluster with machinaA and machineB even though I specified the cluster names differently. How can I prevent unwanted node from joining a cluster?

[image]

Comment: Cluster names should stop them joining. Can you post some logs please?

Comment: In the log, a cluster named [dev] is formed,  I have never specified that in my config,  why is the [dev] cluster forming?  Is it part of design by hazelcast?

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your configurations:

- `tip-ip` => `tcp-ip`
- `member-list:` - addresses should start with `-`
- `indentation` is wrong

So your configuration should look like:

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: cluster1
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled:false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
        - machineA
        - machineB
```

This may solve your issue. If not, please share the logs from all your Hazelcast members (as recommended by Neil Stevenson)

Comment: I have actually correct spellings and hiphen and indentation in the real code.  In fact, I have tried everything kwart suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713563/restrict-members-in-hazelcast-cluster

Comment: Is the cluster separation feature only available in Enterprise Edition? I am using Community Edition

Answer (score 0):

The log you have added shows two lines of interest.
Line 1

```
INFO [main] [machineC]:5701 [cluster2] [4.0.1]
```

and line 13

```
INFO [main] [machineC]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Backpressure is disabled
```

Here `cluster2` and `dev` are the cluster names. The first is as you specified but the second is the default.

Your config file `hazelcast-cluster1.yml` isn't being used. This is why there is a `dev`cluster on *machineA*, *machineB* and *machineC*.

Further back in the logs it should show if an attempt is made to load `hazelcast-cluster1.yml` which would indicate if it hasn't been found or is corrupt in someway.

Comment: Can hazelcast use multiple configuration files each having a cluster configured?  I didnot know that

Comment: I do use cluster1.yml in machineA and machineB since cluser1 lists machineA and machineB as members.    cluster2.yml, on the other hand, lists machineC and machineD as cluster members.  That is why I don't use cluster1.yml.  Furthermore, I am not sure if I can include two clusters in the same yaml file.