# Hazelcast tcp-ip config REST API is not enabled. Unknown protocol: I^@^@

Tags: tcp, hazelcast

The scenario is the same as [Hazelcast tcp-ip configuration cluster: Unwanted IPs join the cluster even after cluster-name is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864032/hazelcast-tcp-ip-configuration-cluster-unwanted-ips-join-the-cluster-even-after/65881874#65881874)
When I finished starting two nodes in cluster1, everything ran OK.  However, when I ran one node from cluster2,  I see the following error after a while.  In the log, I have masked the IP with "machineC_IP" and "transformed_IP".  Note that I have turned on the REST enabled as
hazelcast:
rest:
enabled: true

log:
com.hazelcast.logging.StandardLoggerFactory$StandardLogger [hz.thirsty_brahmagupta.IO.thread-in-1] [machineC_IP]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connection[id=5, /machineC_IP:5702->/transformed_IP:51320, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=5, /machineC_IP:5702->/transformed_IP:51320, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.thirsty_brahmagupta.IO.thread-in-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: REST API is not enabled.
at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:105)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:382)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:367)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:293)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)

com.hazelcast.logging.StandardLoggerFactory$StandardLogger [hz.suspicious_brahmagupta.IO.thread-in-2] [machineC_IP]:5701 [cluster2] [4.0.1] Connection[id=18, /machineC_IP:5701->/transformed_IP:46468, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=18, /machineC_IP:5701->/transformed_IP:46468, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.suspicious_brahmagupta.IO.thread-in-2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: I^@^@
at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:116)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:382)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:367)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:293)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)

Comment: Check the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864032/hazelcast-tcp-ip-configuration-cluster-unwanted-ips-join-the-cluster-even-after/65881874#65881874. If you get `REST API is not enabled` but logs report a cluster name `dev`, it may be your config file isn't being used. So it could be the same problem

Comment: Like I stated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905503/how-to-configure-multiple-hazelcast-tcp-ip-clusters-in-one-yaml-file/65908694#65908694, when I start machineC, only cluster2 config should be used.  Cluster1 config, whose members are machineA and machineB, are not supposed to be used.  Is that correct?  Neil, why did you say " it may be your config file isn't being used."?  In fact, cluster1.yaml is being used when I started machineA and machineB.  It is just not being used on machineC.