# How to configure multiple hazelcast tcp-ip clusters in one yaml file?

Tags: tcp, hazelcast

To configure one cluster in one yml file, I could do:

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: cluster1
  network: 
    join:
      multicast: 
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - machineA
          - machineB
```

However, because of the way the yaml file is structured, I find it difficult to do a yaml file with 2 clusters.  If I do it the following way, it would not work:

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: 
   - cluster1
       network: 
         join:
           multicast: 
             enabled: false
           tcp-ip:
             enabled: true
             member-list:
               - machineA
               - machineB
   - cluster2
       network: 
         join:
           multicast: 
             enabled: false
           tcp-ip:
             enabled: true
             member-list:
               - machineC
               - machineD
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define separate configurations per cluster. What you did is an invalid configuration. Say you have two different configurations: `cluster1.yaml` config and `cluster2.yaml` config. Then all the members of cluster1 should start with cluster1.yaml and the ones in cluster2 should use cluster2.yaml. If you need multiple clusters to be aware of each other - e.g being synchronized, consider using [WAN Replication](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#wan-replication).

In that case the configurations will look like:

cluster1.yaml:

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: cluster1
  network:
    join:
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - A  # uses this config
          - B  # uses this config
```

cluster2.yaml:

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: cluster2
  network:
    join:
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - C  # uses this config
          - D  # uses this config
```